# Setting the weight unit which gets automatically generated

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I am facing this issue since very long now, we have a delivery partner Ecomm express and one of our developers had integrated its API and now he's not working with us anymore.

So what is happening is whenever we book a pick up using the API it automatically takes 1 kg per unit as weight and hence at the end of the month we get charged for 1kg/unit.

We tried contacting the delivery partners to solve this issue and they said there is no issue with their API, they told me to find a file called GSM in magneto where there is a field called `"actual_weight"` and change it to 250 grams. But I don't where can I find this file, they also told me to take a Magneto developers help, so if anyone knows the solution please let me know.

I need to fix this issue urgently. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Patrik, welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, your question lacks the clarity and it seems in order to do the job, you need someone who knows to do the changes (basically a developer). Please hire someone to do this task and it will avoid further mess. "Shooting to air with a vague idea may bring big problems later"

Comment: Hi Rajeev, actually this problem is there with every delivery partner who doesn't have a option to change weight in their API. So i think some one might know how to change the weight unit.

Comment: if someone who has an idea about the Ecomm express API integration can definitely help you if he/she came across this question. Let's hope for the best.

Comment: Actually its not a problem of Ecomm API, its default problem in Magento as we also had used Delhivery as our partners in past and we had the same issue with them. even the Ecomm support guy told me to do the changes in my Magento.